# How to clear basic authentication credentials when loading url in webview android

Tags: authentication, webview, basic-authentication

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebBrowser(userName, password));
   
webview.loadUrl(BuildConfig.WEBVIEW_URL);
```

sending auth using :

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
    handler.proceed(username, password);       
}
```

but only first time it (`onReceivedHttpAuthRequest`) is calling tried to clear cache with all flags but still nothing happens. Can any one help me?